# How to get rate of interest and EMI amount on the basis of months for a payment gateway?

Tags: payment-gateway, payu

The question is related to "Payment gateway" that we are creating for "PayU Turkey". And we are creating this module for X-cart.

But we stucked on a point i.e. Rate of interest and EMI amount.

**For example**, If you are going to pay in Snap deal then while payment you can choose EMI options also. Like AXIS bank can show showing 4 EMI options of (3months Rs. 10846.71/- p.m. 12%), (6months Rs. 5504.29/- p.m. 12%), (9months Rs. 3739.19/- p.m. 13%), (12months Rs. 2849.22/- p.m. 13%).

And if we will select another bank lets say HDFC, then EMI options will be (3months Rs. 10864.55/- p.m. 13%), (6months Rs. 5520.07/- p.m. 13%),  (9months Rs. 3754.40/- p.m. 14%), (12months Rs. 2864.21/- p.m. 14%), (18months Rs. 1990.07/- p.m. 15%), (24months Rs. 1546.72/- p.m. 15%).

So you can see the EMI amount , EMI options (3 Month , 6 Month etc) and rate of interest is changing and depending upon banks. So how we can get these values ?

Right now we are getting EMI options only (See below code).

```
{"meta":{"status":{"code":0,"message":"success"},
"response":{"httpCode":200,"httpMessage":"200 OK"}},
"cardBinInfo":{"binType":"MASTERCARD","binIssuer":"AKBANK","cardType":"CREDIT","country":"Turkey","program":"Axess","installments":
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],"paymentMethod":"CCVISAMC"}}
```

See this image.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically PayU Turkey is not providing the EMI amount. I have discussed with them and they said that simply break the amount as per installment and rest think bank will do.

Answer (score 0):

PayUMoney doesn't provide this way to calculated while you doing paymeny. As you mention you can see SnapDeal website, so they design and make custom way to calculated EMI as bank rules and policy. So you can calculated EMI then proceed to payment. I hope you would understand what i say.

Comment: Thanks Singh for your response.
But somehow we need to show the EMI options and rate of interest. Right now PayU APi is returning the EMI options as mentioned in my code. But there is no provision to show EMI amount and rate of inerest.

Comment: Can you provide sample code which one you have tried ?